# Are k6 http calls asynchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, load-testing, k6

Are `k6` `http` calls asynchronous? When I execute a call like `http.get(url, params)` is `k6` waiting until the response?

If it is asynchronous and let's say I'm executing few calls and I want the response of a one call as the parameter to another call. How can I wait before executing the 2nd call until the response is returned from 1st one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, `k6` currently does not support asynchronous, or more generally, event loop.

You can read [here](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6#script-execution) for more details about how script execution.

**Note**

We have plan to support event loop, but I can't tell you now when it will happen.

Comment: How does it works with a batch call? if I execute 5 requests as a batch and then execute another call after that, is that 2nd call is waiting until all the responses retrieving in the batch?

Comment: No, in batch mode, all requests are made parallel

Comment: True. Calls inside the batch are made parallel. I meant if I execute a post call after a batch call, is that post call waiting until all the responses from batch call is retrieving?

Comment: @Sand Yes, consequent calls are synchronous.

Comment: The answer was edited, to change the first word to `Fortunately`, why is that? Are async bad ?

Answer (score 1):

Please do refer the latest documents on K6.AS per the new release ,v0.43 contains two releases which includes v0.43.0 and v0.43.1. v0.43.0 brings one of the most demanded k6 features: a friendlier syntax for working with asynchronous functionality via Javascript's async and await. Hope this will solve your query.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35013678)

Comment: @kkakkurt how is this not an answer to the question?